# Calling function inside a AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmpp, quickblox

I am using quickblox for an XMPP real-time messaging app running on top of Apache Cordova.

I've attached a screenshot of the function `onChatMessage` which does not return a callback for some reason..
http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample

It works as expected in the browser but once it's loaded within a WebView inside Android or iOS application it failed to return a callback... However, the message is sent successfully from the phone.

Please let me know your thoughts and any help is appreciated.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Hi. This plugin is deprecated - chat is now built into the SDK and you use it like QB.chat.connect() - after which you declare your listeners. I'm afraid we don't have a full sample but please check this link out: http://quickblox.com/alex/websdk/chat.html - it uses the latest version of the SDK. :)

Comment: Hi Alex, i've tried using the new SDK however I can't connect it always returns 'POST https://chat.quickblox.com:5281/ 405 (Invalid hostname.)'. Do you have any idea(s) why?

Comment: Do you see it on http://quickblox.com/alex/websdk/chat.html?